# How to Force a new window only in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am creating a web application in asp.net. In that i have used `window.Open` to open new page in another window. what i want is when this window is fired, it should only get open in IE. even though the user is using that in crome, firefox or any other browser

```
window.open("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Even if it is possible (which I doubt is possible without some hacky and unmaintanable code), why??? And what about users that does not have or **want** IE ?

Comment: Do you want to open IE if it is not the browser currently being used?

Comment: @unicron: Yes i want to do like that

Comment: @SteveB: actually steve i am using reporting rdlc reports. and when i view that in report viewer, print button does not come in the tool bar. its just visible in IE and no other browser have support for that. so because of which i want such type of window

Comment: You can't open another browser in a new window, it's just so impossible it does'nt even need explaining. window.print works (almost) in all browsers if you need a print button.

Comment: @Moiz: as browser don't know each others, what you are asking is to be able to spawn a new process from any browser. This may be possible using some url monikers. But even if you succeed without opening big security breaches, this looks like a very bad design. Why don't you simply add a print button in your html code?

Comment: @SteveB: yes steve, i have that option. i just want to confirm that if that is possible then my work would have been reduced so just asked.

Comment: You should actually rephrase your question to "How to add a print button in a report viewer that works on all browsers?". It's preferable to describe the requirements in your question. This allows us to guide you to either solution, instead of help to sink into some hell-to-maintain application

Comment: @Moiz sounds like you are using an out-of-the-box report viewer that is causing the issue.  Maybe you should rephrase your question to figure out a better way to display your report, or ask for specific help on using that control?

Comment: @SteveB,@unicron: i am using the latest Reporting service of Microsoft.But it actually works on Active x . so other browsers are not supporting. and regarding putting a button i have that idea how to do that thing. so i didnt asked. any ways thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible.

Browsers do not allow webpages to launch arbitrary applications on the user's system (and there is no specific "launch IE" feature either … nor is there likely to be one in the future - browser vendors aren't in the business of making it easy for authors to move their users to competitors!).

Even if they did, not all systems have Internet Explorer available.

Design a web application instead of an Internet Explorer application.

Comment: This is not actually true. ActiveX (evil) or url monikers (dangerous if not mastered, and quite complex) can spawn new processes. But of course, a properly designed web application, cross platform compatible, is **far more preferable**.

Comment: @SteveB — ActiveX is only supported by IE and is fairly locked down. url monikers can't spawn arbitrary applications, you have to have an installer register a specific one.

Comment: Fortunately, a web apps can't alone declare a webmoniker